# Data Tables get selected cell and display it in another page

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I'm working with data tables and model view controller and I want to display selected cells in another partial view.

For example this is my table with data:

```
<table id="display1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><a href="#">0.34</a><td>
<td><a href="#">0.35</a><td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

This is my script:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#display1 tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
        $("#selectedOption").html($(this).val());
    });
});
```

where selectedOption is a div inside a partial view. The problem is that it does not display the selected cell.

Comment: Post the partial view code please

Comment: <div id="selectedOption"></div>

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this updated javascript:

```
var table =  $('#display1').DataTable();

$('#display1 tbody').on( 'click', 'td', function () {
    $("#selectedOption").html( table.cell( this ).data() );
} );
```

and this updated HTML:

```
<table id="display1" name="display1">
<thead>
  <tr><th>1</th><th>2</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><a href="#">0.34</a></td>
<td><a href="#">0.35</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<div id="selectedOption"></div>
```

You also forgot to close your "/td" tags

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nyupftax/2/)

Let me know if this works for you

Comment: this is an example is not my real table,in my real table its everything ok ,i have <thead> and all the tags

Comment: Cool! Glad I could help